# Recommender System - Predict ratings with Random Forest Regressor or Classifier?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, recommender-system

My dataset has clothes that contain features for every cloth. Let me show you the dataframe to understand.

[image]

Every cloth is rated between [0,10] with step 0.5

In bibliography and paper conferences some tend to use regression models for recommendation and others classifiers. Of course i understand the fact that classifiers are for categorical data and regression for continuous but in my case should we treat ratings as categorical values even if they are ordinal?

For a random forest model what will be the best option from a scientific point of view.

Any invokes to scientific articles will be appreciated

Comment: You want to do classification or recommendations? Those are different problems. What exactly you want to use this data for? What question you want to answer with it?

Comment: i want it for recommendations

Comment: Than what exactly do you want to predict to make the recommendations?

Comment: the ratings of the product and if i predict high ratings i want to recommend them